# Is enrollment in Apple Developer program necessary for getting a certificate and private key pair?

Tags: ios

I am in the process of learning to write apps in swift for iOS. I want to generate an ipa file with xcode to test on a phone.

(1) Is it absolutely necessary to have a certificate and private key pair in order to generate the ipa? If not, how can I do it?

(2) If the answer to (1) is yes, is it necessary to join the Apple Developer program. If not, how can I get a certificate and private key pair without an Apple Developer account?

Comment: Note, the Apple Developer program is free to join and if you aren't publishing on the App store you don't need to pay to test apps on your device. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973799/ios-9-new-feature-free-provisioning-run-your-app-on-a-device-just-with-your-ap/32249026#32249026

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You absolutely need Apple Developer Certificate to create ipa file. You can either test it with test-flight or iTunes or diawi, but to generate an ipa you must need a developer account.

While start learning, it is not must. But when you enter the stage of testing push notifications or publish for Beta-testing, you MUST need developer account