# How to create IOS .IPA file and share it, using FREE Apple ID?

Tags: ios, xcode7, ipa

First, this is not a duplicate of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721) as my question is about distribution not creating of IPA file.

I have developed an iOS application using Xcode 7 in OS X 10.11 and I was trying to create and publish a .IPA file for it, enabling others to be able to download and install it on their iPhones.

But I have tried numerous ways and haven't had any success.

- I have a FREE apple ID account and although I have joined the
  development program I have not purchased it.
- I have set the "code signing" option to "Don't code sign" and archived the app. Then I couldn't use "export" option in "Xcode organizer" for "Ad-hoc" or "Developer" distribution because the Developer Team info required, was not available in the drop down list. (Guess because my account was not a developer account). So I used a command to generate the ipa file from the archive file. Then I uploaded this file to diawi.com or installrapp.com and it didn't work. (In installrapp.com I got the error "Didn't find any provisioning profile).

In abstract form, I want to publish my ipa file for testing, but it is not important for it to be on apple store or on any valid store, just somewhere that users are able to download it, and I don't have their user id's on their devices because they can be anyone, and I can't connect their device to my system in order to install the app, again because they can be anyone.

I just want to know that "Is there anyway to publish my app, probably using .ipa file, without paying for apple developer account, in a way that users are able to install it without connecting their device to my device or jailbreaking their device, because they can be anyone?"

And is it possible for me to send my IPA to someone with developer account to upload the file using his account somewhere for test, like diawi.com?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create ipa in xcode 6 without Apple Developer account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account)

Comment: @ozgur, No it's not. They all just talk about creating the IPA file. Well i have created it but i need to distribute it and upload it!

Comment: Upload to where? You need to create a provisioning profile first in order to distribute it. Here is how you can do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973799/ios-9-new-feature-free-provisioning-run-your-app-on-a-device-just-with-your-ap

Comment: @ozgur, As mentioned in my question, this link provides the method for creating the provisioning profile, only for the devices connected to my system. I want it to be uploaded to somewhere like diawi.com or installrapp.com and anyone be able to download it, without connecting thier device to my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do requires an Enterprise Developer License.

Find out more here: [Apple Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)

However, if you distribute your app using this program on a website or any other means, you are breaking Apples terms of service.

This means they are free to revoke your signing cert at any time.

Your best bet is to pay for a normal developer license and start using Testflight. I know this is not what you want to do, but honestly you have to respect the terms of service that Apple has created or you have no legal recourse when Apple shut you down.

Why do you need to use Testflight?

Apps code-signed with provisioning profiles other than an enterprise license require UDID's of all devices expected to be using the application. TestFlight which allows you to collect UDID's through a web-portal which then creates a provisioning profile for your application, or you can sign people up using the TestFlight app which will capture the UDID. All you need to do this is have a testers email address.

To sum up:

- There is no legal way to do this for free. Enterprise licence offers 
  the functionality, but it costs $299 and using it the way you want to
  breaks Apples ToS. Apple have spent a lot of time, effort and money
  to prevent people providing apps like this easily, cheaply or legally.

With good reason:

1. [Google Malware Spread through Third Party Apps](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3032247/security/android-root-malware-is-widespread-in-third-party-app-stores.html)
2. [Root access gained through 3rd Party App Stores](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/user-beware-rooting-malware-found-in-3rd-party-app-stores/)
3. [Xcode from third party sites infects IO on Apple Devices](http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2015/09/novel-malware-xcodeghost-modifies-xcode-infects-apple-ios-apps-and-hits-app-store/)

Comment: First, I haven't tried to violate any terms of service, I have basically asked a question in order to avoid such things. I don't want to use my app for enterprise use, I just want testers to be able to download it, bu collecting their ids is hard. Bu t iguess using the normal developer account would be enough for me, as this is not an enterprise app. Am i right?

Comment: Ang given what i said, if i pay for a 99$ dev account, i definetly need the UDIDs of users?

Comment: Apologies if you thought I was making the assumption you had already broken ToS. Just from your original post it sounded like you wanted to post it outside the walled garden of the iOS app store (on something like a website, or distributing through an email, which would break ToS). If you got a $99 developer account you could use TestFlight which allows you to sign up users through their email address. More info here : https://developer.apple.com/testflight/