# Is it possible to OTA install an iOS App that is signed with FREE Apple Dev Account

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ipa, ota

Note that I'm aware of these posts:

- [How to create IOS .IPA file and share it, using FREE Apple ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089612/how-to-create-ios-ipa-file-and-share-it-using-free-apple-id)
- [How to create ipa in xcode 6 without Apple Developer account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account)

I don't want to send the app to anybody for testing (not knowing their UUID).

My situation is this

- I have the .ipa file. Can generate it using 'xcodebuild' command or by drag&drop the archive's .app file into iTunes
- this .ipa is codesigned with my free AppleID
- the provisioning profile, generated by XCode contains 3 device UUID

What I'd like to know: why I can't install this .ipa file to the device which UUID is presented in the provisioning profile.

If I try to install it using iTunes it starts to install, but after the progress bar (progress circle to be exact :P) on my device completes, the app icon just disappears and iTunes is stuck in the syncing process. No error message is shown.

I also tried to install it using [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) and got the error message "Unable to Download App". Although it shows me that my device's UUID is in the app's provisioning profile.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is because you are using a free account; The free level is intended to allow you to develop and test on your own devices.  If you upgrade to a paid account you can create an ad-hoc distribution build and get access to TestFlight

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. I know that. "...allow you to develop and test on your own devices". This is what I want but with archived app. Isn't that possible?

Comment: I thought this was only possible with the $299 Apple Enterprise Developer license ?  This is what we have in our company, and with that, it is possible to put the .ipa file on a website, and users can download & install our in-house app directly from a webpage.  As you've seen though, when an install goes wrong, Apple's error reporting is either nothing, or misleading ("XXX cannot be installed at this time...")

Comment: @MikeGledhill You don't need Enterprise Account to do that. With a simple $99 account you can do ad-hoc distribution. But again: I don't want to distribute. I don't want to give it to testers whose UUID is unknown to me. I'm asking if it is possible to install archived (.app/.ipa) app to devices which I have the UUID in the app's provisioning profile with only a free dev account

Comment: I believe that the only deployment option available with a free account is directly connected to your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I believe the free account only allows you to build and install directly on the device with a development build.  Also, those builds' provisioning profile expires after 7 days, so the OTA builds wouldn't last very long anyway.

If you want more details of why the install is failing, you should look at the device console during the installation.  It will give you more details on the exact reason for the failure.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to watch the device console log. Now there is a proof that the answer is no. I get this when installing from iTunes:
`Feb 22 20:53:08 XXXX-iPhone installd(MobileSystemServices)[43] <Notice>: 0x16e037000 -[MIInstallableBundle _validateBundle:validatingResources:performingOnlineAuthorization:verifyingForMigrator:allowingFreeProfileValidation:error:]: 746: The bundle being installed with bundle ID com.XXX.XXXXXX.ios is authorized by a free provisioning profile, but apps validated by those are not allowed to be installed from this source.`