# How to run apps on Real devices using Xcode 8 without enrolling to Apple's Developer Program?

Tags: ios, xcode8-beta2

In previous version of xcode 7, we can run our app on real device by adding apple id to xcode account and then selecting team.

But as now release of xcode 8 beta 2, there is no "fix issue" button instead of that there is "Automatically manage signing" Available.

And it gives following Error.
[image: Xcode signing Error]

i am trying to get solution for this.
So if anyone have solved that issue, Help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973799/ios-9-new-feature-free-provisioning-run-your-app-on-a-device-just-with-your-ap

Comment: https://livecode.com/how-to-create-a-free-ios-development-provisioning-profile/

Comment: i know in xcode 7 it works but i'm talking about xcode 8

Comment: Just enter Apple ID into Xcode preferences and make sure you did not set any provision profile in buildsetting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to connect a device to Xcode and allow it to register it on your personal team. This will allow Xcode to create profiles for you (profiles cannot be created unless there is at least one device registered).

Comment: Well, and how I can unregister device used previously?

Comment: This helped me obtain the right solution - the project must have "automatically manage signing" ticked.

Answer (score 4):

You need to register a device.

To do so:

1. From the project navigator, next to the Run/Play button, click on your project name and find the Devices menu. You will see "No devices connected to Mac".
2. Click on that and connect your device to your MacBook via USB cable.
   The device will show up on the MacBook.
3. On the device, accept to trust the device.
   Xcode will register the device and do the necessary tasks.
4. Select the device. This should automatically resolve the signing error/provisioning profile issue.
5. Click Run/Play to run the project on the selected device. This will run the app on the device.

Later you can remove the USB cable to test your app on the device. If you would like to copy the changes to your device, connect the device again and run.