# Is it possible to test app on the device without developer program? [Xcode 9.4 - Code Signing Error]

Tags: xcode, xcode9.4

I don't register 'Apple Developer Program', but I want to test the iOS application on my devices.

Is it possible to test the iOS app on my device without registering 'developer program'?

I tried to build the app on my device, but 'code signing error' occurs.

[image: Code Signing Error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run apps on Real devices using Xcode 8 without enrolling to Apple's Developer Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301229/how-to-run-apps-on-real-devices-using-xcode-8-without-enrolling-to-apples-devel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed bundle identifier to the form of com.[myName].[AppName], then it works.
I think I can freely use any words for [myName] if it does not conflict.

I refered to
[iOS 9 new feature Free Provisioning (Run your app on a device, just with your Apple ID, without Apple developer membership)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973799/ios-9-new-feature-free-provisioning-run-your-app-on-a-device-just-with-your-ap)