# Run iOS application on device with a free Apple account

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to run iOS application on iPad with a free device. When I press the fix issue button in xcode, I get this error

> No Devices
>
> Creating a profile requires having a device registered in the Member Center.

I tried to add a device in the member center but my account looks quite different from [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Art/11_mc_change_team_role_2x.png). I just have the "additional resources" section, I do not have a "Program Resources" section. Is it not possible to run code on a device with a free account ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973799/ios-9-new-feature-free-provisioning-run-your-app-on-a-device-just-with-your-ap

Comment: than we can just close every question related to iOS and apple devlopment ...
@Rogier thanks

Comment: @User1238 No, we merely strive to close every question which is off-topic as per the [help].  Yours is not a problem which can be solved by programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Add your free account in xcode. Create provision profile for it (free).

When run the project set this profile. I should run fine. I am also using a free account and running projects in my iPhone.