# Do I need Apple developer program to use Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase

Just as title says is it necessary to use the Apple developer program to use Firebase or alternatives? I don't want to deploy my app to app store just for my use...

Comment: No need, just make it configurable to make all call in any mode, say crash: upload DSYM file for debug mode too.

Comment: You can use free Apple developer account, but it has many limitations when dealing with real iDevices. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32249026/326017