# Adding UDID of testers with free developer account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 with a free apple developer ID. No problem to test the app with an iPhone that is directly connected to my Mac. Xcode generates a valid provisioning profile and added UDID of my iPhone.

Now I want to send the app to a tester but couldn't find a way to add his UDID or generate a valid provisioning profile. Xcode produce archive but prevent exporting it. It says: 'Distribution requires enrollment in the Apple Development Program' and gives me a link to enrollment that needs payment.

I could produce .ipa from command line but of course without tester's UDID inside!

[Apple documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW15) shows how to add a new UDID but my accounts on apple developer is not contains such menu items, it only guide me to enrollment and pay to join apple developer program (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMYeK.jpg)

I have tested other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973799/ios-9-new-feature-free-provisioning-run-your-app-on-a-device-just-with-your-ap), with these solutions I could generate something but only contains my UDID again. [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) and [fabric beta](https://www.fabric.io) also didn't help, how they can help if I can not add tester's UDID?

My question is: Is it possible at all to send app (.ipa or anything) to tester with a free account or I should pay?

Comment: No. you should pay.

Comment: did you find solution for this? if yes please tell me

Comment: No, I paid it. But it was more than 5 years ago and I don't know if anything has changed since then time. @AminRezaew

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to send .ipa or anything without enrolling to Apple Development program. You need to join apple developer program and then only you are able to distribute your app for testing as well as on App Store.

You can enrol yourself at : https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/

And then you are able to register devices into your account and after creating valid certificate and provisioning profile you are able to send your app for testing.

Answer (score 0):

No. You must enroll (99$ per year).

Then you will be able to test on devices by adding them as development devices.
You'll also have access to TestFlight, wich will allow you to invite testers using their Apple IDs