# Xcode error (Failed to create provisioning file)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to ios programming and was going to start my first project but these two error messages were thrown when using Xcode 9.4.

1. Failed to create provisioning file.
2. No profiles for "**(my Bundle Identifier)** " were found

I don't have a developer's account and am using my personal apple id. Is this why these errors are showing? I looked up some ways to get rid of these but

1. Changing the Bundle Identifier to something unique didn't work
2. The destination it's running does not say "generic device"

I only plan to use Xcode locally using a simulator. Is there a way to get rid of this error message or can I just ignore it and keep developing my project?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32249026/2830676

Answer (score 1):

If you try to run your project on the real device(iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch) and if you do not have apple developer account then it will show error message like below image,

[image]

this is showing because I am trying to run my project on the real device and I am not providing/added provisioning profile in Xcode.

**What is provisioning Profile?**

It allows you to copy your programs directly to iPhone, iPod or iPad to test them which is more accurate than only having the simulator.

**If you do not have developer account in apple then you can not run the code/project on the real device**

Comment: is there a way to get around this? I'm also learning and i don't want to pay $99 just for a simple ToDo app that i am not going to publish in app store

Answer (score 0):

> I only plan to use Xcode locally using a simulator. Is there a way to
>   get rid of this error message or can I just ignore it and keep
>   developing my project?

You don't need any account to run your app in simulators. If you want to get rid of these messages or run the app in real devices, you have to create an Apple Developer Account (maybe using your apple id).

After you create your developer account, login it in your Xcode.

> Xcode > Preferences > Apple IDs

Then select your personal team, enter your bundle Id and hit `Fix Issue` in the project panel and it should be good.